# Solve the initial value problem x'=Ax

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A =
\begin{array}{cc}
-2 & 1 \\
5 & -4 \\
\end{array}$

$x(0) = 
\begin{array}{cc}
1\\
3\\
\end{array}$

I undertsand that this is an eigenvector problem, and I got the values of $ -3+ \sqrt{6}$ and $ -3- \sqrt{6}$. I am unable to calculate the eigenvectors from here.

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be either one of your eigenvalues. Compute the matrix $A-\lambda I$. An eigenvector is a nonzero element of the nullspace of that matrix. Do you know how to find an element in the nullspace of a matrix? For a $2\times2$ matrix, there is an exceedingly easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the eigenvalue $\lambda = -3 - \sqrt{6}$, we find $[A-\lambda I]v_1 = 0$ and arrive at a RREF of:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{5} \left(-1+\sqrt{6}\right) \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0$$

We choose $b = 1, a = \dfrac{1}{5} \left(1-\sqrt{6}\right)$, so:

$$v_1 = \left(\dfrac{1}{5} \left(1-\sqrt{6}\right), 1\right)$$

Since we have conjugate eigenvalues, we can write the eigenvector for the second eigenvalue as:

$$v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{5} \left(1+\sqrt{6}\right),1\right)$$

You can now write:

$$x(t) = c_1 ~e^{\lambda_1 t}~v_1 + c_2~ e^{\lambda_2 t}~v_2$$

Use the IC to find the constants.

Your final solution should be:

> $x(t) = \dfrac{-4 e^{\left(-3-\sqrt{6}\right) t}+\sqrt{6} e^{\left(-3-\sqrt{6}\right) t}+4 e^{\left(-3+\sqrt{6}\right) t}+\sqrt{6} e^{\left(-3+\sqrt{6}\right) t}}{2 \sqrt{6}} =\dfrac{1}{3} e^{-3 t} \left(2 \sqrt{6} \sinh \left(\sqrt{6} t\right)+3 \cosh \left(\sqrt{6} t\right)\right)  \\y(t) =\dfrac{-2 e^{\left(-3-\sqrt{6}\right) t}+3 \sqrt{6} e^{\left(-3-\sqrt{6}\right) t}+2 e^{\left(-3+\sqrt{6}\right) t}+3 \sqrt{6} e^{\left(-3+\sqrt{6}\right) t}}{2 \sqrt{6}} = \dfrac{1}{3} e^{-3 t} \left(\sqrt{6} \sinh \left(\sqrt{6} t\right)+9 \cosh \left(\sqrt{6} t\right)\right)$

Comment: Not really necessary to do any row reduction, was it?

Comment: No, but I think s/he should know the general approach.